# How to setup a remote json API for Rails for authentication and session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to rails and are have a pretty basic understanding of the Devise Gem. Besides the CRUD and views I'm not clear on what it provides that could help me for a AngularJs app talking to a Rails Json Api.

At the moment I'm hand rolling things ie. for security I have I exchange a HTTP Header token between client (js) and server. I'm also using the Railscast #250 for user authentication - but as I don't see how to apply the SessionController for a remote client.

Are there any strategies I could employ for authentication and managing session via a remote json API?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to be a little more thorough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use devise for something like this because there's only a small part of it you'd be using anyways

### Dont

You pretty much just don't use a session.  All you need to do is pass in basic authentication each time, and in the application controller you determine if its valid, if not just send them back an auth error.

Example request: `http://username:password@example.com/api/endpoint`

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_auth!

  private
  def check_auth!
    username, password = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::user_name_and_password(request)
    user = User.find_by(username: username)
    if user && user.encrypted_password == SomeEncryptFunction(params[:password])
      @current_user = user
    else
      raise "error"
    end
  end
end
```

### But if you want to...

Then what you can do is update a `DateTime` field on the user when they first auth (which starts their session), then on subsequent calls they can just pass a token you give them that you you check for each time they sign in.  You also check that only a certain amount of time has passed since they first authed, otherwise their session is invalid.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :check_auth!
  before_filter :login!

  private
  # Note: I don't remember the actual devise method for validating username + password
  def login!
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    if user && user.valid_password(params[:password])
      current_user = user
      current_user.update_attributes(
        authenticated_at: DateTime.now,
        authentication_token: Devise.friendly_token
      )
    else
      raise "error"
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_auth!

  private
  def check_auth!
    if valid_token(params[:token])
      current_user = User.find_by(authentication_token: params[:token])
    else
      raise "error"
    end
  end

  # Returns true if token belongs to a user and is recent enough
  def valid_token(token)
    user = User.find_by(authentication_token: params[:token])
    user && user.authenticated_at < DateTime.now - 1.day
  end
end
```

Comment: Great thanks for that - gave me some useful ideas on token authenticity too. I noticed you use Devise tokens here, I've used BCrypt and SecureRandom - in this case I could do without Devise completely do you think?

Comment: yeah, definitely go with it! SecureRandom is great for tokens and BCrypt is great for passwords, so you're all set

Comment: `User.find_by(authentication_token: params[:token])` is susceptible to [timing attacks](http://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/) and is [the reason why TokenAuthenticatable was removed from Devise](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/). Consider doing something like [this](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6) instead.

Comment: @Ashitaka's link didn't work for me -- try https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6

Comment: Pasted the link twice, it seems. I wish comments were editable. Thanks, tyler.