# Angular/Ionic/Phonegap app with rails API web service Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cordova, devise

I have recently decided to experiment with Angular/Ionic/Phonegap with a Rails API Web Service as backend, to create my first mobile app.

I am from a Rails background and usually use Devise to handle my user authentication/User object to which I assign Roles using Rolify.

Doing some reading, it seems to me that this is not the same methodology that I would have to follow for a mobile app as seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188790/how-to-setup-a-remote-json-api-for-rails-for-authentication-and-session)? What  I would ideally like to have, is for users to sign in / up using their Facebook accounts, which would create their User record. My web service will then assign the required roles etc.

So my question:

1. Should I be using Devise/Rolify/Pundit ?
2. Is there a better/more efficient way to handle this process using this stack?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devise with the omniauth-facebook gem. There are some nice [articles](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) out there on how to implement.
Along with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908836/omniauth-for-rails-and-ios-authentication) you should hopefully be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Any backend auth service should really work fine. We use Devise and have found it to work well with angular and ionic. We recently wrote a tutorial on how to set up [Ionic with Devise](http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/8/26/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-two) that you might find useful.